# return specific values from database with node and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently trying to populate a table in my node/express application. I have a logged in user and a database with an "owner" field that matches the logged in users username. I'm trying to return all the values where the owner field matches the username of the logged in user

```
router.get('/userproducts', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('products');
  collection.find({owner:'#{user.username}'},{},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing that leaps out at me is that you're ignoring the error in your `collection.find()` callback. Errors are there to tell you why something doesn't work, kinda like StackOverflow. ;)

Comment: Which error is it @RobRaisch ? sorry I'm pretty new to this language so trying to get my head around it

Comment: Find method expecting only one parameter, and .toArray() method for running query
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find

maybe you use some ORM, like mongoose? which mongodb nodejs driver you use?

Comment: @vmkcom I am using monk instead of mongoose, il have a look at the link though! thanks

Comment: @user I refer to the `e` argument in your `collection.find()` callback which, if it exists, indicates that the call has failed. The first line of your callback should deal with a possible error, as in `if(e) { throw e; }` or `if(e) { console.log(e.toString()); return; }`